# What chemical makes the ‘smoky’ flavour in smoked paprika?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I really detest ‘smoky’ flavours eg smoked paprika. It tastes like fumes to me. What chemical/ substance do these contain that causes this please

Comment: How should it taste like? BTW, there will be dozens to hundreds different chemicals, contributing to the smoky smell/taste.

Comment: Maybe you don’t like [phenols](https://ift.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1365-2621.1966.tb03284.x).

Comment: Could be other substances like ketones or carboxylic acids, or a [combination.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3951573)

Comment: Thank you. I wasn’t assuming anything. I know nothing about it, that’s why I asked the question. I don’t have a scientific background hence I came here to find out. Very interesting answers. Thank you all

Answer (score 2):

The National Institute of Health has provided a good [list of chemicals found in "smoke" flavoring](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3951573/). Here are just a **few**:

```
Phenolic compounds
  Phenol
  2-methylphenol
  4-methylphenol
  2-methoxyphenol

Aldehydes and ketones  
  Propanal
  1-hydroxy-2-butanone
  2-methyl-2-cyclopenten-1-one
  1,2-cyclopentanedione
  2,5-hexanedione

Furans and pyrans
  Furan-3-carbaldehyde
  Furan-2-carbaldehyde
  Tetrahydro-2,5-dimethoxyfuran
  1-(2-furanyl)-ethanone
```

###### and the list continues *ad nauseam*...

As to which of these **you** find objectionable, you'd have to get samples and test-taste (well, test-smell) each. Or you could arrange to be in the lab when these are fractionated, sniffing the output stream of a gas chromatograph, and have the most bothersome analyzed.

#### *De gustibus non est disputandum.*

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you.

Comment: @Jane If you like this answer, please consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark.